# Strong duality for a particular moment problem

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, duality

Reading the paper in this [Link (see pag 13)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05116.pdf) with the objective of understanding a topic related to stochastic optimization I came across a problem in demonstrating one of the theorems. The situation is the following:

**The context:** Let $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space where $\Xi\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\widehat{\xi}_{i}\in \Xi$ for $i=1,\ldots,N$ and $\ell(\xi):=\max_{k\leq K}\ell_{k}(\xi)$ where $\ell_{k}:\Xi\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions. We denote by $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ the set of probability distributions supported on $\Xi$. We consider the infinite optimizatión program
\begin{align} 
 &  \left\{\begin{array}{cl} {\displaystyle\sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi)} }&{\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\ell(\xi)\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)} \\ \mbox{s.t.} & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)\leq \varepsilon.} \end{array} \right.  \tag{P} 
\end{align}

We know that the dual problem is

\begin{align} 
 &  \left\{\begin{array}{cl} {\displaystyle\inf_{\lambda} }&{\displaystyle  \sup_{\mathbb{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{M}(\Xi)}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\ell(\xi)\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi) +\lambda \varepsilon -\lambda \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi) \right)} \\ \mbox{s.t.} & {\displaystyle \lambda \geq 0.} \end{array} \right.  \tag{D} 
\end{align}

We denote $\mathrm{Val(P)}$ and $\mathrm{Val(D)}$ the optimals values of $\mathrm{(P)}$ and $\mathrm{(D)}$ respectively.

**Assumption:** The paper I am reading establishes the following assumption:

> **Assumption 1.** ***[Convexity]***
>   The uncertainty set  $\Xi\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is convex and closed, and the negative constituent functions $-\ell_{k}$ are proper, convex and lower semicontinuous for all $k\leq K$. Moreover, se assume that $\ell_{k}$ is not identically $-\infty$ on $\Xi$ for all $k\leq K$.

**The problem:** If the convexity Assumption 1  holds, I need to show that we have strong duality, that is, I need to show that $\mathrm{Val(P)}=\mathrm{Val(D)}.$

**Remark:** According to the paper I am reading this is a consequence of a extended version of well-known strong duality result for moment problems, in this sense, the paper cite the following work:

> A. Shapiro, ***On duality theory of conic linear problems***, in Semi-Infinite Programming, M. A. Goberna and M. A. L´opez,
>   eds., Kluwer Academic Publishers, 2001, pp. 135–165

In this work, in Proposition 3.4, they show strong duality for the optimization problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \max_{\mu\in\mathcal{C}} & \left\langle \varphi, \mu \right\rangle \\
\mbox{s.t.} & \mathcal{A}\mu-b \in K \end{array}   \right. \tag{1}
$$
where the context of $\mathrm{(1)}$ is the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Is (P) a particular case of (1)? If the answer is yes, then how can I make this evident?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
$\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ is the space of all probability measures defined on the measure space $\Xi$ with Levy distance and superscript means usual direct product of spaces.

${\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_{i}(d\xi)\leq \varepsilon}$ can be rewritten as $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb Q)=\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{Q}_i)_{i=1,\cdots,N}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\mathcal{A}_{\hat\xi_i}\mathbb{Q}_{i}$
You can verify that $$\mathcal{A}_{\hat\xi_i}:\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^N\rightarrow \mathbb R, \mathbb{Q}\mapsto \int_{\Xi}\left\|\xi-\widehat{\xi}_{i}\right\|\mathbb{Q}_i(d\xi)$$ is linear in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the sum of linear operators is still linear.

So $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^N\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a linear operator and the constraint is $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{Q}_i)_{i=1,\cdots,N}-0\in \{r\in\mathbb{R} : 0\le r\le K\}$

Now the inner product is just the dual product $\langle\varphi,(\mathbb{Q})_{i=1,\cdots N}\rangle=\int_{\Xi}\varphi (d\mathbb{Q_1}+\cdots+d\mathbb{Q_N})$. Here $\varphi=(\varphi_1(\omega)\cdots\varphi_N(\omega))\in L(\Xi)$ the space of all integrable real functions defined on $\Xi$, but with the setting of (P), you are just choosing a special case that $\varphi(\omega)=(\varphi_1(\omega)\cdots\varphi_N(\omega))=(\frac{1}{N}l(\omega),\cdots,\frac{1}{N}l(\omega))$. In short the inner product is defined on $L(\Xi)\times \mathcal{M}(\Xi)^N=L(\Xi)\times \oplus_{i=1}^N \mathcal{M}(\Xi)$

Comment: In your answer, who is $\mathcal{M}^{+}$?

Comment: @Henry.L I would also like to know an answer to Diego's question.  The bonus is yours if you can specify your answer.

Comment: @matematicaActiva Sorry for the late reply, I obviously missed Diego's comment for some reason, $\mathcal{M}(\Theta)$ is the space of all probability measures endowed with Levy distance.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca Sorry I missed your comment see my comment below.

Comment: @Henry.L In the context of (1) we have the $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p}$. Of your answer I deduce that $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}$, but this raises doubts me because in the context of (1) we have that $\mathcal{X}$ is the linear space of signed measures generates by $\mathcal{M}^{+}$.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca  I think $\mathcal{M}^+=\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}$, and $\mathcal{X}$ is the space generated by $\mathcal{M}^+$ because we need a factorizable structure on $\Xi^N$ or you can see $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}=\otimes\mathcal{M}(\Xi)=\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$ in this case only..

Comment: @Henry.L When you say $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}=\otimes\mathcal{M}(\Xi)=\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$ you are actually saying that all measure in a product space is a product measure which is not true. Why in this case is this true?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca It is not true...I meant if $\mathcal{X}$ is the space generated by $\mathcal{M}^+$, then it doe not matter $\mathcal{M}^+$ being one of these three right? Because those additional points in $\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$ can never be extremal points and hence do no additional good to the optimization.

Comment: @Henry.L According to what you say we can say $$\mathcal{X}=\mbox{span}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})\right)=\mbox{span}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}\right)=\mbox{span}\left(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi)\right),$$ am I right?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca in this problem yes because that adds no extremal points.

Comment: @Henry.L One last question, in the context of (1) we have that $\mathcal{C}$ is convex cone in $\mathcal{X}$, I think it must be $ \mathcal{C}=\mbox{cone}\left\(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N}) \right\) $, am I right?
If this is correct, we can say $$\mathcal{C}=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N}) \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N} \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \right)$$
Is this last correct?

Comment: @matematicaActiva Yes, I think it suffices to consider convex cones in this case. But let me know if that is not enough because that may fail the original arguement.

Comment: @Henry.L Where can I find a proof of $$\mathcal{C}=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N}) \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N} \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \right)?$$ For me $\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ is the set of all produc measures on $\Xi^{N}$, Is my conseration correct? In this sense, we have $\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \subset \mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$. **Is  $\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ a convex set?**

Comment: @matematicaActiva I already said that my usage of "=" means there will not be additional extremal points, so subset is fine, but in this case I feel it should be equal. subset is already enough for the argument in OP,